# Efficient Algorithm for Proving Arbitrary Region in Higher-Dimensional Space is Bounded

Tags: algorithms, sampling, monte-carlo, programming

I have a region in *n*-dimensional space. I know nothing about this region, save these things:

- To start, I am given the coordinates of a single point that I know is within the region
- The region is contiguous
- I can perform a computation on any point to determine whether or not it's also inside this region

By utilizing #3, what is the most efficient algorithm for proving, to a given sampling resolution, that my high-dimensional region is bounded?

(The region I am personally studying lies on a hypertorus, but I will also accept an answer that just applies to normal Euclidean hyperspace.)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you already know that the space is bounded and only want to produce a proof that it is (like a bounding box of negative tests)?

Comment: @dtldarek While not exactly correct, that's close enough that you can treat the question as if it were the case. Technically, my region exists on a hypertorus, so I showing it's not bounded would consist of finding a contiguous line that extends longer than the length of the torus in a given direction. But for the purposes of this question, you can assume the region is in regular Euclidean hyperspace, and I know it's bounded and just want to prove it.

Comment: Ah, I see. The detail about torus is I think highly relevant, so please include it in the question.

Comment: @dtldarek Ok, done.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "proving to a given sampling resolution"?

Comment: @WillieWong I'm referring to the fact that, for this question, it is clearly impossible to prove with 100% certainty that the region is bounded, because there could always be some very thin "corridor" of the region that goes in between the points you've sampled. So I'm essentially asking for an algorithm that proves the region is bounded so long as no sufficiently small "corridor" exists, and presumably the more points you sample the smaller the upper bound for this corridor size becomes.

Comment: The OP says that they _will also accept an answer that just applies to normal Euclidean hyperspace_. One might as well restrict attention to a two-dimensional problem in the Euclidean plane. Because then it already becomes sort of a challenge, at least for me. As long as we cannot even catch up with a similar problem in two dimensions, why then hunting for a solution in hyperspace? Still apart from the well known [Curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).